# Residual plot Diagnosis

Tags: r, multiple-regression, least-squares, residuals, heteroscedasticity

I am working on a multiple linear regression model to investigate the relationship between several independent variables such as profitability, leverage, board size, percentage of women on board, industry(dummy), media exposure (dummy) and the dependent variable "ESG disclosure score" (A Bloomberg rating that rates companies from 0.1-100 based on the amount of ESG disclosure). The Q-Q plot and vif both look fine and the residuals vs. leverage plot does not show any influential outliers. However the residual vs. fitted plot shows a downward pattern as visible in the plot below.

[image: Residual vs. fitted plot]

From previous searches I learned that this pattern may show up due to the lower bound of the dependent variable (in my case the 00.1 of the Bloomberg index). A Breusch-Pagan test has shown that my data is highly heteroscedastic. I have now included heteroscedastic robust standard errors in the model. Is this enough to satisfy all OLS assumptions or is it necessary to do transformations? I already tried to take the log of dependent and independent variables (excluding the dummies) but the pattern did not change at all.

Moreover, I am unsure if this pattern actually biases estimates or only standard errors due to heteroscedasticity.

I am still a R/statistics beginner and would highly appreciate some help to finally resolve this issue, many thanks!

Comment: Since you have bounded data, a good idea is to apply a transformation to the DV into (0,1) and fit a beta model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RobertLong ! I am still a beginner in stats but now read an introductionary paper about beta regression models. It seems to be working. However, I found out that there is a lot of uncertainty around validating beta models as the method is relatively new. My question is: it is enough to add heteroscedasticity robust standard errors or might there also be a bias in coefficients? I saw several other studies relying on the same dependent variable using normal multiple linear regression. None of these studies has even mentioned problems of heteroscedasticity...